# Почему не приходят данные из формы в Elemenor?

Tags: wordpress, форма, elementor

после отправки приходит письмо, но вместо заполненных данных в нем только тема письма и почему то цифра 1. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

даже если в настройках указать [all-fields], ничего не меняется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в админке данные отображаются как надо. Что не так с этой формой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]